# Assume asymptotic value in a limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

Is it possible to give `Mathematica` a limit about's function at infinity?
For example I would like to

```
Limit[F[r], r -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> F[\[Infinity]] == 0]
```

To evaluate to zero. What are my options? And will is there a way to impose stronger conditions, for example if $F(x)$ would behave as $1/r^2$ at infinity is it possible to assume this in `Mathematica`? So that for example one might calculate

$$
\lim_{r \to \infty} r F(r) = 0 \quad \text{for} \; F(r) \approx 1/r^2 \; \text{with} \; r \gg1.
$$

Comment: What would you do with this if it were possible? What do you need this  functionality for? Maybe there's a different approach to your actual underlying problem.

Comment: Finding a Green's function for a ODE.. I wanted to check that the Green's function that I found is really a Green's function. I.e. $L \int G(x,y) F(y) dy = F(x)$ with $L$ being some differential operator (acting on $x$). Since the expression is quite complicated I choose the upper limit as integral to be some value instead of $\infty$ to "help" `Mathematica`, so now I'm finding the limit of that expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, F, r, t, x]
```

Use [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) to define [`UpValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) for `F`

```
F /: Asymptotic[F[x_], x_ -> Infinity] = 1/x^2;

F /: Limit[F[x_], x_ -> Infinity] = 0;

UpValues[F]
```

[image]

```
Asymptotic[F[r], r -> Infinity]

(* 1/r^2 *)

Limit[F[r], r -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)
```

`F` cannot be buried any deeper in the LHS of the `TagSet`. Use a replacement rule when `F` is buried deeper.

```
asymFinf = F[t_] -> Asymptotic[F[t], t -> Infinity]

(* F[t_] -> 1/t^2 *)

Asymptotic[a*F[r] /. asymFinf, r -> Infinity]

(* a/r^2 *)

Limit[a*F[r] /. asymFinf, r -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)

Limit[r*F[r] /. asymFinf, r -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)

Limit[a*r^2*F[r] /. asymFinf, r -> Infinity]

(* a *)
```